# Trouble with the libPng.dylib from freetype 2.5.3

Tags: xcode, libpng

I have installed freetype-2.5.3 on OS X (10.9.4) in my local directory in which I park all science software (/Users/t/Science/local), and now my other codes are running into trouble, i.e.

:/Users/t> make
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_png_create_info_struct
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /Users/t/Science/local/lib/libPng.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
make: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
make: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch
:/Users/t> /usr/bin/xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

The Xcode path seems to be okay. How do I get libPng.dylib from my system to be the default again?

Many thanks!

Comment: I know I can solve this issue with a simple sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libPng.dylib /Users/t/Science/local/lib/libPng.dylib  but that's not the point.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem because I installed libpng with brew. Running the following command solved the problem :

`brew uninstall libpng`

And if you need both the default mac libpng and this one...good luck. I had to install/uninstall libpng with brew oftently.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have replaced the libpng that was built with a "__cg_" prefix on its exported names.  You could try reinstalling libpng from source, using the

> "--with-libpng-prefix=__cg_"

configure option, which may be how libpng was installed previously.  That option became available in libpng16 (libpng-1.6.0 but not really completely working until libpng-1.6.3).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you have set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable and have it pointed to /Users/t/Science/local/lib ... that will cause the system to pick up YOUR libpng when it is trying to resolve the path to its libpng.

Don't do that.  If you find that setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH "fixes" some problem, it is almost certainly not the actual fix to the problem.  It is more likely that you have incorrect dylib ids in your libraries such that the resulting linkage is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line `LIBS += -L/opt/local/lib` from the .pro file helped.