# brew update fails because of missing symbol in libpng

Tags: macos, homebrew, libpng, osx-yosemite

I tried to run `brew update`, but then I get the following error:

```
$ brew update
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_png_create_info_struct
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libPng.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

How do I go about solving this problem? I'm using version 0.9.5 of `homebrew` and I'm on 10.10.3 of OS X.

Comment: `libpng` seems to make my system think the Xcode command line tools aren't installed either. If I run `brew doctor` with `libpng` installed then it tells me the command line tools aren't installed, but if I uninstall `libpng` it doesn't complain about the command line tools.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066445/trouble-with-the-libpng-dylib-from-freetype-2-5-3/26068840#26068840